# Why is "num[0]+=1 if X else num[1]+=1" invalid syntax?

Tags: python

```
import random
num = [0,0]
for i in range(100):                                
    num[0]+=1 if random.randint(0,1) == 0 else num[1]+=1
print(num)                                            ^here
```

This seems to be recognised as invalid syntax
thanks

Comment: You can't put a *statement* in those positions; only an *expression* is valid.

Comment: oh right cheers

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
import random
num = [0,0]
for i in range(100):                                
    if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
        num[0]+=1
    else:
        num[1]+=1
print(num)
```

Comment: Thanks, it was actually meant to be a challenege to get the fewest amount of lines, but I did this:     import random
    num = [random.randint(0,1) for i in range(100)]
     print(num.count(1),num.count(0))      
cheers

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute statement in `else`. You coud use such construction if you would need to increase `num[0]` by 1 if a condition has been met and by something different if not.